# Windows Forms Resizing And Overlapping UserControls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, resize

I have a Windows Form with 9 identical user controls that are directly adjacent to one another. On my screen the form looks fine, but when running a coworkers machine, the window gets resized and the user controls overlap. Does anyone know how i can prevent them from overlapping? I don't mind that the window is resizing on different machines, I just don't want any lost information or partially hidden elements.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: using docking or any of layout panels?

Comment: the controls lie in a panel, or a container of some sort?

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mention, they are in a groupbox inside a tabpage. Also, I left docking and anchoring as the default values, but I have done some experiementing and anchoring might be the way to go. Does that seem correct? Any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://en.csharp-online.net/FlowLayoutPanel). It won't work in every situation, depending on what kind of controls you intend to place inside it. I'm not sure what your user control look like, but I just added a FlowLayoutPanel and added about a dozen buttons inside it, and it takes care of 
 adjusting the layout for me when the end-user resizes the form, maintaining padding around each button and avoiding overlapping.

If your user controls can flow around each other, and it doesn't matter if they are side by side or one over the other, you may want to check this out.