# Winforms controls layout issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I am struggling to make my layout better in my windows form application.

This is what I basically need to do. I have `label` and `picturebox`.

Text of the label set run time from the program and text length would be vary time to time.

I need to place my picturebox right after the text ends (2-3 space in between)

I have tried to achieve this by setting `Anchor` and `Dock` properties. but did not get as I need. Controls are still overlapping.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Put them both in a flow layout panel.

Comment: I am inheriting label from another form

Comment: What do you mean that you inheriting label from another form?

Comment: Inherited controls could be an important part of the problem. Add this information to the question.

Comment: Also, put the panel in the same form where the label is. Let it be inherited, just like the label is.

Answer (score 0):

You can position your image on label text change event:

```
    private void label1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            int labelLocationX = lbl.Location.X;
            int imageLocationX = labelLocationX + lbl.Size.Width + 10;
            img.Location = new Point(imageLocationX, lbl.Location.Y);
    }
```

Comment: I was look for a way to do this by setting a property rather than handling it from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a FlowLayoutPanel

This has also been mentioned in this link [FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585594/windows-forms-resizing-and-overlapping-usercontrols)

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work you need (like the others already mentioned) a `FlowLayoutPanel`. But additionally you need also some other properties set to get the job done:

- First add a `FlowLayoutPanel` to your form or user control.
- Set the `Dock` property to `Fill` of the flow layout panel.
- Add a `Label` to the flow layout panel.
- Add a `PictureBox` to the flow layout panel.
- Set the `Width` and `Height` of the picture box to the desired values.
- Set the `MinimumSize.Heigth` of the label to the picture box height.
- Set the `TextAlign` of the label to `MiddleLeft`
- Set the `Padding.Right` of the label to 10 (or whatever space you like).

Now if you change the text of the label, the picture box will always be aligned to the size of the label.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, create a panel to hold both items. Set only the properties in picturebox Dock to Fill and in label Dock to Top. Add first the picturebox to the panel, then after that the label. However, docking invalidates any margin assignments. One could insert a dumb panel of height 10 in between label and picturebox.